# Bind two images together to be dragged

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for some help with a script to drag two images together at once. I currently have a script that allows me to drag thumbnail images into a collection bin to be saved later. However, some of my thumbnails have an image positioned over the top of them to represent these thumbnail images as "unknown" plants. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction as to how I would go about binding these two images together to be dragged. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var limit = 16;
var counter = 0;
$("#mainBin1, #mainBin2, #mainBin3, #mainBin4, #mainBin5, #bin_One_Hd, #bin_Two_Hd, #bin_Three_Hd, #bin_Four_Hd, #bin_Five_Hd").droppable({
    accept: ".selector, .plant_Unknown",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
                counter++;  
        if (counter == limit) {
            $(this).droppable("disable");

        }


            $(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());


            $("#cbOptions").show();
            $(".item").draggable({
                    containment: "parent",
                    grid: [72,72],
            });
    }
});
$(".selector").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 700,
    opacity: 0.75,
});

 $(".plant_Unknown").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 700,
    opacity: 0.75,
});
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: [Website](http://www.plantcombos.com/html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may surround the current draggable elements with a container which will be draggable instead of the previous ones.

```
<div class=".container">
    <div class=".selector">...</div>
    <div class=".plant_Unknown">...</div>
</div>
```

And then, replace your draggable calls with:

```
$(".container").draggable({
   helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    revertDuration: 700,
    opacity: 0.75,
});
```

PS: After seeing the website, you may also consider your link tag as the suggested container.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to create an object(function or variable) that contains both elements, then drag the object.